# How to make tooltip or something like a tooltip that pops up instantly on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know how to make a simple tooltip using `title="here's a tooltip"`, but I want it to pop up instantly on hover instead of waiting a second. Is this possible using anything? It could be html, css, javascript, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

I'm not amazing with CSS, but it has something to do with the :hover selector, which allows you to change the properties of a thing when hovered over.